# What are the differences between speech acts and implicatures?

Tags: pragmatics, meaning, discourse

Here's what I have come up with.

What I understand is that implicature is always indirect and not explicit, so the hearer must infer from the context.
Speech act, on the other hand, may be direct and explicit Ex. Use imperative form to command and or with performative verb ex. I command you...

Is this correct?

Also, implicature can be Cancelled or reinforced, and it is indeterminate. But is speech act also cancellable?

Comment: Speech acts are events, taking place between speakers and listeners in real time. Implicatures are mental constructs that are conventionally attributed to certain types of speech acts (where _types of speech acts_ must be very broadly construed to include all of syntax, semantics, pragmatics, and phonology). Broadly speaking, one is data and the other one is theory; they're not the same kind of thing at all.

Comment: An implicature is a proposition being conveyed "between the lines" in an utterance context. A speech act is an event, an action being performed by an utterance.